# Can anybody show me how I can use graded color scale to highlight a row in excel without VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can anybody use graded color scale to highlight a row in excel without VBA?

I already have mixed cell reference set up. And I want to use a 2-color scale based on their values. For the Minimum I have `Formula,=0,white`. For the Max `= Formula, =100, red`. Basically I want to do is have the selected line `(=IF(ISBLANK(V4),"",TODAY()-V4)`, get more red as the "Schedule Due Date" falls further and further behind us. And I don't know if this possible with the 2-color scale.

Comment: Thank you pnuts and thank you PhilK...   It worked... changing the "Formula" to "Number" was the trick.  Thank you.       Now I'm working with 'mixed cell references', And I want to highlight the 6 previous cells going by that 'ISBLANK" statement.  Is it possible to have a 'Graded Color Scale" to highlight the 6 previous cells?   I'm using 'mixed cell references to Cond. Format a row' with the 'active cell' to the upper right.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cells Rules. *General answer, but provide more information for a more in-depth answer. For example, how many grades do you want? What are your conditions? etc.*

Comment: I already have mixed cell reference set up.  And I want to use a 2-color scale based on their values.  For the Minimum I have Formula,=0,white.

Comment: So you want 2 colors. What should each color reflect?

Comment: I already have mixed cell reference set up.  And I want to use a 2-color scale based on their values.  For the Minimum I have Formula,=0,white.  For the Max = Formula, =100, red.     Basically I want to do is have the selected line (=IF(ISBLANK(V4),"",TODAY()-V4), get more red as the "Schedule Due Date" falls further and further behind us.  And I don't know if this possible with the 2-color scale.

Comment: You would have to set each 'range' of it being 'further' with a 'darker' shade of red.

Comment: Thank you pnuts and thank you PhilK... It worked... changing the "Formula" to "Number" was the trick. Thank you. Now I'm working with 'mixed cell references', And I want to highlight the 6 previous cells going by that 'ISBLANK" statement. Is it possible to have a 'Graded Color Scale" to highlight the 6 previous cells? I'm using 'mixed cell references to Cond. Format a row' with the 'active cell' to the upper right.